# FHIR Resource Rule; FHIR Rule Management and Rule Definition

Tags: rule-engine, rule, business-rules, hl7-fhir

I'm new to FHIR and resources.

1. I'm on the search for a specific resource type, is there a resource type for Rules?

Rules contain 0 to * conditions and 1 to * actions. All conditions are connected with the 'and'-Operator. If all conditions are met, all actions shall be performed.

2. If there is no specific resource-type for such rules, how am i able to define rules with FHIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is decision support.  Look at look at http://hl7.org/fhir/2016sep/decisionsupportservicemodule.html.  If you're thinking more about protocols, look at http://hl7.org/fhir/2016sep/plandefinition.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I got one more question, STU 3 seems to be not released yet, are the listed resources already available?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "available".  They're published in the 2016sep ballot release.  However, their official publication as part of a "standard" release (STU3) won't occur until the end of this year.  Neither resource was part of STU2.  If you need to do this in STU 2, you'll need to implement equivalent functionality using Basic.